# Sort alphabetically , list of book titles contained in a CSV file

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort a file that contains book information. I can sort the names of book authors however I cannot sort the list with book titles.

```
public class Book { 
private String Id;
private String title;
private String author_firstName;
private String author_lastName;
private String genre;

public Book(String Id, String author_firstName,  String author_lastName, String title, String genre) {
    this.Id = Id;
  
    
    this.author_firstName = author_firstName;
    this.author_lastName = author_lastName;
      this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;

}


 static class SortByTitle implements Comparator<Book> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Book b1, Book b2) {

        return b1.title.compareTo(b2.title);

    }

}
   static class SortByAuthor implements Comparator<Book> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Book b1, Book b2) {

        return b1.author_firstName.compareTo(b2.author_firstName);

    }

}
```

> > **TEST PROGRAM (MAIN )** <<<<<

```
Collections.sort(books, new Book.SortByTitle()); //title

Collections.sort(books, new Book.SortByAuthor()); //author
```

//        books.forEach(b -> { //b valera cada um dos livros dentro.. lambda temporaria
//            System.out.println(((Book) b).getId()); //typecast , b object // casting que forca o generics a entender qual o tipo de objeto a ser recebido

```
books.forEach(t -> { //b valera cada um dos livros dentro.. lambda temporaria
            
            System.out.println(((Book) t).getTitle()); //typecast , b object // casting que forca o generics a entender qual o tipo de objeto a ser recebido
        
           
       

    });
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Secret Reunion
Kiss the Bride
ParaNorman
Exploding Girl
Curse of the Pink Panther
Son of Paleface
Wreck of the Mary Deare
Meet Me at the Fair
Wog Boy
Intimate Strangers (Confidences trop intimes)
Cinderella
Weekend It Lives
Ballad of Nessie
Hot Pepper
```

Comment: Please can you clean up your code so that it does not show unused code.

Comment: Your code is sorting by Author after doing the initial sort by Title, so the output will be by Author?